# Chaing async method on Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have following class.

```
class Element {
  Future<Element> findById(var id)async {
     await networkRequest();
     return this;
  }

 Futute<Element> click() async {
    await networkRequest();
    return this;
 }
}
```

I want to achieve the something like.

```
main() async {
  var element = Element();
  await element.findyById("something").click();
}
```

But I'm not able to do so because element.findById() returns future. How can I chain these async methods.

Comment: You want to chain the response of findById() & click() ?

Comment: findById return the future of Element.

Comment: Are you using Dart 2.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there's no special syntax to chain futures, there are two semantically equivalent ways to do what you want:

1) Two separate `await` calls:

```
await element.findById("something");
await click();
```

2) Chaining with `then`:

```
await element.findById("something").then(() => click());
```

Comment: I"m aware of first one but I want to chain it directly without using then. Is it impossible?

Comment: @Mandip I don't think there's a generic way, but, for example, if `click()` accepted an `Element` argument, that would look like `element.findById("something").then(click)`, which is, I believe, as short and clean as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

Use this,

```
await (await Element().findById("1")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final el = await element.findyById("something");
await el.click();
```

Comment: While your code may provide the answer to the question, please add context around it so others will have some idea what it does and why it is there.

Comment: Honestly, it’s easier for me to remove the answer than to give a detailed comment on this code.